# Mouse cuts out with increased memory use

Tags: windows-7, usb, memory, mouse

My Logitech USB mouse cuts out as though it had been unplugged more and more frequently. All power-saving USB options have been disabled in Windows 7, the devices have been deleted and reinstalled through device manager, and I've confirmed the mouse itself isn't the problem, as it works fine on another computer, while other mice experience the same issue on this PC.

It does seem as though the disconnects are more frequent the more memory is in use—with just this browser window, it only happens once every minute or two, but if I have multiple programs running concurrently, it can happen for longer periods and much more frequently.

Neither restoring to a restore point nor wiping the hard drive and reinstalling Windows has resolved this issue.

Is there a solution other than just "install more memory"? Considering that this has only become an issue in the last six months, I feel like adding more memory will treat the symptom more than the disease.

Comment: This may actually be some driver spamming the USB hub. On some laptop configurations, the "fingerprint scanner" would cause this. I once fixed this on my daughter's computer by uninstalling/reinstalling an apple software package that started querying for her phone multiple times a minute...

Comment: If your CPU or memory is being maxed out, or at least extremely high usage it can definitely affect the mouse. Can you tell us what your CPU and memory usage stats are when the mouse stuttering occurs?

Comment: It is probably because the mouse driver is being swapped out of RAM, and contention is delaying the allocation of memory to read it back in. Is your page file big enough? Increasing its size is the first thing to try. The "rule of thumb" of initial page file size as double the RAM size is nonsense: the swap size depends on the memory used by running processes, so the less RAM you have, the more swap you need. It takes a long time to increase the page file, and this can cause long pauses while it's done. Try setting the initial size manually to at least 4 or 5 times the RAM.

Comment: Swapping should not cause a device disconnect, only a delay in response, if any. The whole thing sounds to me like some USB signal integrity degradation in your PC. If it is common for all RF wireless mice, then it could be interference with some WiFi.

Comment: I'd like to point out also that so far this is all using wired mice.

Comment: Currently have 8GB RAM & updated my pagefile size to range between two and five times that quantity. Tried to take a screenshot of the task manager the next time the mouse d/c'ed; it looks like heavy CPU usage might be a bigger contributor than memory, which has been steady: http://imgur.com/Nsz1gg7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a problem specific to two different mice that I tried, as a third mouse did not have this issue. It's possible the configuration of my specific computer aggravated the issue with the mice such that the issue was invisible on other computers.

Answer (score 2):

I've just increased my RAM from 2GB to 4GB, it definitely improved performance and ended the constant stuttering of the mousepad I experienced with 2GB. System is Dell Inspiron 1525 on win vista.